# Export SQL to new tab in xlsx

Tags: sql, export-to-excel

With both Toad and Oracle SQL Developer when exporting to xlsx, you have the ability to also export the sql to a 2nd tab as part of that export. I'm trying to attempt the same in DBeaver.
Next, once you export to xlsx (or anything for that matter) is there an option that would automatically open that output document?

I've installed the Office add-on which gets me to xlsx and the results export perfectly. I've reviewed the options but nothing is jumping out.